# Jenkins SVN plugin failed when removing files (Checksum mismatch)

Tags: java, bash, svn, jenkins, maven-3

We encounter a strange error with Jenkin today. After investigating, we find that it's due to the fact that we delete some files in SVN, which cause a problem in Jenkin SVN plugin.

As I investigate, it seems this bug was known but it hasn't been fixed yet. So that upgrading to a newer SVN plugin version is not a solution(we are using Jenkin 1.474).

Our temporary fix is that "always checkout before building". But this is clearly very slow and takes much time for big projects. So that I'm looking for a way to (at least) detect the SVN problem in post-build scripts when it happens, and probably send an email to notify the developers.

Here's the error log:

```
Building in workspace /workspace-directory/workspace
Cleaning up /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/aaa/workspace/.
Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/aaa/workspace/logs
Deleting /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/aaa/workspace/target
Updating svn://address/trunk@HEAD
U         src/main/some_file.java
D         src/main/another_file.java
U         src/main/other_files.java
ERROR: Failed to update svn://address/trunk@HEAD
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155017: Checksum mismatch while updating '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/aaa/workspace/src/main/address/.svn/text-base/StudioSignUpController.java.svn-base'; expected: '39fc987bbeb8cd332e6b94abfb934720', actual: 'e9fa300ee28a2b1e15b2273f4b14ae18'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:85)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:69)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNEditModeReader.driveEditor(SVNEditModeReader.java:250)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNRepositoryImpl.update(SVNRepositoryImpl.java:1503)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.update(SVNUpdateClient16.java:557)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient16.java:414)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc16.SVNUpdateClient16.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient16.java:324)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldUpdate.run(SvnOldUpdate.java:27)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.old.SvnOldUpdate.run(SvnOldUpdate.java:11)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1221)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:292)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:315)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:295)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNUpdateClient.doUpdate(SVNUpdateClient.java:391)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.UpdateUpdater$TaskImpl.perform(UpdateUpdater.java:136)
    at hudson.scm.subversion.WorkspaceUpdater$UpdateTask.delegateTo(WorkspaceUpdater.java:144)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.perform(SubversionSCM.java:789)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:770)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$CheckOutTask.invoke(SubversionSCM.java:753)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:842)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:824)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:743)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM.checkout(SubversionSCM.java:685)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1245)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:589)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:88)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:494)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1488)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:477)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:236)
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E155017: Checksum mismatch while updating '/xxxxx/.svn/text-base/SignUpController.java.svn-base'; expected: '39fc987bbeb8cd332e6b94abfb934720', actual: 'e9fa300ee28a2b1e15b2273f4b14ae18'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNUpdateEditor15.textDeltaEnd(SVNUpdateEditor15.java:637)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNAmbientDepthFilterEditor.textDeltaEnd(SVNAmbientDepthFilterEditor.java:221)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNCancellableEditor.textDeltaEnd(SVNCancellableEditor.java:130)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNEditModeReader.processCommand(SVNEditModeReader.java:176)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.svn.SVNEditModeReader.driveEditor(SVNEditModeReader.java:232)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: svn: E155017: Checksum mismatch while updating '/xxxx/.svn/text-base/SignUpController.java.svn-base'; expected: '39fc987bbeb8cd332e6b94abfb934720', actual: 'e9fa300ee28a2b1e15b2273f4b14ae18'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:189)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:141)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNUpdateEditor15.textDeltaEnd(SVNUpdateEditor15.java:634)
    ... 33 more
no change for svn://some_address/trunk since the previous build
No emails were triggered.
```

Answer (score 2):

We have occassionally seen the problem with some builds, but we normally just clear the workspace and then rebuild.  (From Jenkins, Navigate to the job, then "Workspace".)

There are a couple of different plugins that may help with detecting and possibly actually taking some actions based on the issue.

- [Warnings Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Warnings+Plugin) - parses the console output and looks for built in and user defined patterns that it reports as Warnings.
- [Log Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Log+Trigger+Plugin) - triggers downstream jobs if a specific trigger is found in the console log.  (Perhaps have an SVN "clean-up" job that is triggered?)

Of these, I have only used the Warnings Plugin myself.

Answer (score 0):

These threads from Jenkins JIRA and JetBrains are interesting:
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-14550
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83673#comment=27-379397

As you mentioned, the issue remains open in Jenkins. JetBrains believe they have corrected IDEA with the updated svnkit:  svnkit 1.7.5-v1.

Also noted in the jetbrains issue are some strategies to fix the issue using the commercial tool SmartSvn, an svn client which has a special feature "Validate Admin Area".

I am going to try to update the Jenkins JIRA issue with a note about the svnkit to see if that results in a fix.

EDIT:
Actually, it looks like the January Jenkins Subversion plugin, 1.4.5, takes care of this issue. After installing and manually re-starting, the mismatch went away.

Comment: Seems to have taken care of the problem. Had to manually re-start Jenkins, but the build worked immediately (which was unexpected - thought I'd have to wipe out the SVN download).

Comment: manually restart Jenkin? I don't understand. Why we need to restart Jenkin?

Comment: If it only works after manually restart Jenkin, I would prefer wiping the workspace instead.

Comment: Seems like that part was just a bug with Windows running it as a service. Specifically, Jenkins leaves a Java process running which I assume is looking for the re-start of the server, but that Java process is holding onto the port that the main Jenkins process is looking for, so it fails to load with port in use. I did not try this update without re-start. Possibly that might have worked.